# Adding a format to an element of this code?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I have a dictionary being returned from a webpage as a `.JSON()` object that I am formatting using the code below:

```
responser = responser.json()

teamStatDicts = responser[u'teamTableStats']

for statDict in teamStatDicts:

    mylookup = ("{tournamentName},{tournamentId},{regionCode},{tournamentRegionId},{teamName},{teamId},"
    "{minsPlayed},{ranking},{rating},{apps},".decode('cp1252').format(**statDict))
```

This would give ma sample output of:

```
Premier League,2,gb-eng,252,Arsenal,13,75,1,6.22145454545,5,1.0,4.5,5.5,
```

In this example I would like to apply a format to the item `{rating}` so that it only has two decimal places. Is it possible to adapt the code above to do this?

Thanks

Comment: can you please update `teamStatDicts[0]` or any item in `teamStatDicts` for better understanding, Thanks

Comment: @Md.Mohsin hi, thanks for replying. i'm not sure what you are asking of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format allows specification of precision and type like this sample:

```
>>>"{0:.2f}".format(23.2245)
'23.22'
```

That would be `"{rating:.2f}"` in your case.

This is documented in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language